# How to align my navbar with my content container in CSS

Tags: css

I'm reworking a design of an app a friend gave to me just so I can learn some more CSS while starting out.

I wanted the app to be designed like a window in a window so I had margins added to all elements, 90% of it looks fine but it's not really responsive so I must be doing something wrong.

This is how it looks on my monitor (the bottom of both content and navbar is aligned):
[image: monitor]

This is how it looks on the laptop's monitor

[image: laptop]
The bottom of the content container is sticking out. Now I know the problem is because I aligned it using the max and min-height and doing it manually, so I would need to know the code to do it properly so it's responsive on all screens.

Current code:

Navbar:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.096);  
box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgba(69, 90, 100, 0.08);
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
border-right-width: 2px;
```

container:

```
position: relative;
top: 70px;
margin-left: 280px;
min-height: calc(95vh - 82px);
max-height: calc(95vh - 82px);
background-color: #f0f0f0da;
margin-right: 30px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

My body also has a margin of 50px on all

Hope I explained my problem properly and thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `display: flex; display: wrap;` for parent elements

Try to define a `width: 100%;` for both elements.

`max-width: 30%;` for `.nav`

`max-width: 70%;` for `.container`

Comment: will that deal with the bottom height problem as well? I thought with was fine, or is the width pushing it down.

Comment: @MarkoŽilić Just the `display: flex` will fix the height problem. It is a popular same height problem, which can be fixed either by giving fixed heights in pixels e.g. or by using flex: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/#flexbox-method

Comment: Try to don't use a max-height